# Condition for induced measure on quotient group to be atomless

Tags: real-analysis, group-theory, measure-theory

Suppose that $G$ is an uncountably infinite abelian topological group with probability measure $\mu$ where $\mu$ is atomless in the sense that $\mu(\{g\}) =0$ for any $g\in G$.

Suppose that $H \leq G$ and that $\mu'$ is a measure on $G/H$ such that $\mu'(X) = \mu(\pi^{-1}(X))$ for any measurable $X \subset G/H$.

I am curious about what additional conditions would make $\mu'$ atomless as well. These could regard the topology on $G$, the algebraic properties of $G$, or the properties of $\mu$ or $\mu'$.

Comment: $\mu,\mu'$ have to be defined on some $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $G$ and $G/H$ and the projection map has to be measurable for all this to make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$H$ must not be too big, in the sense that if $\mu$ is atomless, then $\mu'$ will be atomless if and only if every coset, $gH$, has $\mu$ measure zero.